# Display the last x elements of a sharepoint list

Tags: list, sharepoint

I am trying to display the data of a SharePoint list. I use CamlQuery to retrieve the list data and I need to display the **latest twelve** items from the list in **ascending order**.

I've find a solution with row limit and by ordering my data in descending order, the problem is to reordering my data in ascending order. I try to find a way to directly have my data in the right order but I find nothing.

Thank you for your help.

MarilynS

Comment: When do you want to reorder ?while adding items to the list?

Comment: Each month, a new line is add to the list each and we use this list to create a graphe. I retrieve the data to build the graphe and i only need the lastest twelve elements.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add an OrderBy in your CAMLQuery like this :

```
<Query>
<OrderBy>
<FieldRef Name='Modified' Ascending='True'></FieldRef>
</OrderBy>
</Query>
```

You specify the field (Created or Modified can work in your case) to order and "Ascending='true'" and indeed, RowLimit is the way to do.

Comment: Ascending='False' because we want to fetch the latest 12 records not the first 12. Also we can add Ascending='False' but on the basis of ID field and not modified fiedl

Comment: Hello, i've already try this method. With this method, my data are displayed in descending order unfortunately i need to display them in ascending order. That why, i try to find a way to reordered my data after or to get directly  the latest data with the right order

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Query>
<OrderBy>
<FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='True'></FieldRef>
</OrderBy>
</Query>
```

After this you can save the result in a list Collection and parse through the records and display the first 12 records or in the quesry only you can add a row limit of 12 to fetch only 12 records.